# How to specify 'exp' without 'ttl'?

Tags: lexikjwtauthbundle

Our security policy requires that users must relogin at 00:00:00, so we can't hardcode some ttl for token in the config. What is the preferable way to create token with specified expiry date like '2017-03-08 00:00:00'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [writing and using your own encoder service](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-encoder-service.md), computing your token lifetime dynamically.